# Form a new group from the given list of groups which satisfies a collective score between two integer number k1 and k2.

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

There are n group with members in it. Members are assigned some scores.  All the members in the same group have same value . Then form a group from this  groups which satisfies a collective score between two integer numberk1 and k2.

example :

```
group1 : {.5,.5,5}
group2 : { 3 }
group3 : { 2 }
group4 : { 1 }
group5 : { 1.1}
k1 = 2.5 and k2 =3.5 Group size = 3.

possible solutions : (.5,1.1,1),(.5,.5,2),(.5,1,2). .
```

what are the possible subsets ?

I can only think of a naive algorithm, is there any better method or similar problems ,please give some suggestions. It is actually an important part of my work. Is there any dynamic programming method available like subset sum?

Comment: Scale values by 10 and use integer subset sum solution

Comment: what if the number of  group increases, isn't it little bit complex ???